# scrollToEnd in Angular 8 didn't emit an event

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to handle an event reaching end of scroll in select component, and, it seems, the event is not even emitted.

But at the same time, similar events like 'open' work fine.

I use Angular 8 in my project.

```html
<ng-select
  ...
  (open)="onOpen()"
  (scrollToEnd)="onScrollToEnd($event)">
</ng-select>
```

```js
onOpen() {
  console.log('open');
}
onScrollToEnd(e) {
  console.log('scroll to end');
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz code?

Comment: What is ng-select? Do you mean [this](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) library? It's better to mention it in the question title and description.

Comment: Is `scrollToEnd` a custom `ng-select` event?

Comment: could you please share your full code?

Comment: I mean this functional  [link](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/events) 
I found that if I set more than 20 data elements, then an event is generated. But I still have no idea about the reasons for this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in CSS. More precisely in scaling and CSS. 60% scale and the current CSS broke the code. The browser did not understand that the end of the list was reached.

Comment: I had a similar problem and for me the solution was to turn off the virtual scroll.